# Launch OpenVpn from windows command line?

Tags: cmd, openvpn

I have managed to do what I want using this awful two lines code:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin" 
start openvpn.exe --config Netherlands1-UDP.ovpn --auth-user-pass info
```

I would like to do it in one line. It seems easy but it doesn't work. Maybe it's because of the space in "Program Files".

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/76919567/185565  how to use a cmdine and also provide a custom config file folder. You don't need to copy open files inside the openvpn installation folder.

Answer (score 0):

To run a command all in one line, it would be something like:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin" && start openvpn.exe --config Netherlands1-UDP.ovpn --auth-user-pass info
```

Comment: Ideally, I would like something like ` start "C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin\openvpn.exe" --config Netherlands1-UDP.ovpn --auth-user-pass info`

Comment: Post the error that you're getting. Also, try without the `start` word

Comment: It just does nothing, when I open the bat file it closes the window instantly

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `OpenVPNServiceInteractive` is running, because from its description :

> It allows OpenVPN GUI and other clients to establish OpenVPN connections without administrative privileges in a secure way.