# How can I use the command line to connect using OpenVPN *CONNECT*

Tags: openvpn, openvpn-connect

There are lots of examples here about how to use the command line to connect to OpenVPN.
I can't find any examples for OpenVPN **Connect**, which is OpenVPN's proprietary client using their access server.

I've tried

```
"C:\Program Files\OpenVPN Connect\OpenVPNConnect.exe" --command connect
```

but that doesn't do anything that I can see.
Other examples want a configuration file which I don't see with the Connect version.
Is it possible?

NOTE: the reason I want to is that my OpenVPN connect disconnects every 24 hours. When that happens I have to re-enter my credentials and log back in.
I don't know why it does that but I'd like to automatically reconnect when it disconnects.

**added later**
The disconnect after 24 hours is a setting in OpenVPN Connect.
You can change it for up to 1 week (168 hours).
I would still like an option to re-connect automatically.

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/76919567/185565   . Your config file could use `auth-user-pass service_userpass.auth` line and that text file two lines: 1st line is username, 2nd line is password.

Comment: This appears to only work with OpenVPN and not OpenVPN *Connect*.